# Force Min and Max values of colormap in pandas style

Tags: python, pandas, colormap, pandas-styles

How to force min and max value range when styling a dataframe column ?

Example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['column'], data = [-1, 0, 1, 2])
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm_r')
```

This produces a column where value 0 is red ; however I would like 0 to be white, i.e. the middle of the 'coolwarm' colormap.

In this example, my understanding of the problem is that the default colormap interval maps my data [-1 : 2].

I would like to set it to [-2 : 2]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `vmin` and `vmax` as follows:

```
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm_r', vmin=-2, vmax=2)
```